Not Able to update version of LWC component
I have updated the Lightning Locker API Version to 61.0 after that I'm trying to update API version of my component but am not able to do
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import fetchIpDataWrapperEditMode from '@salesforce/apex/ESMX_Create_Case_CaseLines_Controller.fetchIpDataWrapperEditMode';
import formFactorPropertyName from '@salesforce/client/formFactor'
import handleUpsertCaseLines from '@salesforce/apex/ESMX_Create_Case_CaseLines_Controller.handleUpsertCaseLines';
import getCaseLineDataTNM from '@salesforce/apex/ESMX_Create_Case_CaseLines_Controller.getCaseLineDataTNM';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CaseLine_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/SVMXC__Case_Line__c';
import LINESTATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SVMXC__Case_Line__c.SVMXC__Line_Status__c';
import getCustomSettings from '@salesforce/apex/ESMX_Create_Case_CaseLines_Controller.getCustomSettings';

const ipcolumns = [
    { label: 'Is Selected', fieldName: 'isSelectedcheckbox', type: 'boolean' },
    { label: 'Installed Product', fieldName: 'caseLineIP', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Serial Number', fieldName: 'caseLineSerNum', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Product Code', fieldName: 'caseLineProdCode', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Product Name', fieldName: 'caseLineprodName', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Functional Location', fieldName: 'caseLinefunLoc', sortable: "true" },
    {
        label: 'Line Status', type: 'lineStatusPicklist', fieldName: 'caseLineStatus', wrapText: true, initialWidth: 150,
        typeAttributes: {
            options: { fieldName: 'picklistOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'caseLineStatus' },
            context: { fieldName: 'caseLineIPId' }
        }
    }
];

const caselinecolumns = [
    {
        label: '',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 75,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'utility:delete',
            title: 'Delete',
            variant: 'border-filled',
            alternativeText: 'Delete'
        }
    },    
    { label: 'Case Line', fieldName: 'caseLineNum'},
    { label: 'Installed Product', fieldName: 'caseLineIP' },
    { label: 'Serial Number', fieldName: 'caseLineSerNum' },
    { label: 'Product Code', fieldName: 'caseLineProdCode' },
    { label: 'Product Name', fieldName: 'caseLineprodName' },
    { label: 'Functional Location', fieldName: 'caseLinefunLoc' },
    { label: 'Service Status', fieldName: 'clServiceStatus'},

    {
        label: 'Line Status', type: 'lineStatusPicklist', fieldName: 'caseLineStatus', wrapText: true, initialWidth: 150,
        typeAttributes: {
            options: { fieldName: 'picklistOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'caseLineStatus' },
            context: { fieldName: 'autoRecNumber' }
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Mass Update Reference Line', fieldName: 'clMassUpdate', type: 'checkbox', editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            value: { fieldName: 'clMassUpdate' },
            context: { fieldName: 'autoRecNumber' },
            namefield: 'clMassUpdate'
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Select Line', fieldName: 'clSelectLine', type: 'checkbox', editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            value: { fieldName: 'clSelectLine' },
            context: { fieldName: 'autoRecNumber' },
            namefield: 'clSelectLine'

        }
    },
    { label: 'Reason for Cancellation', fieldName: 'clReasonCancel', editable: true }
];

export default class Esmx_edit_ip_tnm extends LightningElement {
    //
    @track pageNumber = 1;
    @track clPageNumber = 1;

    @track maxPage;
    @track maxcLPage;

    @track lastButtonClass;
    @track nextButtonClass;
    @track firstButtonClass;
    @track previousButtonClass;
    @track recordCount;
    @track sourceName;
    @api currentPageNumber;
    @track currentCLPageNumber;

    @api maxPageNumber;
    @track maxclPageNumber;

    @api maxPerPage = 250;
    @track maxCaselinePerPage = 20;

    @api totalRecords;
    @api showpopupbool

    loaded = false;
    caseloaded = false;

    @api locpmcasevalues;
    @api salesorg;
    @api contactselected;
    @api conlanguage;
    @api casesubject;
    @api casedesc;
    @track totalBatchRecords = [];
    @track MaxRecordsPerBatch;
    @track totalclRecords;
    @api finalCaseId;


    @track insideSearch = false;


    handleIpRecNumChange(event) {
        this.ipRecNum = event.detail.value;
    }
    handleIPProdChange(event) {
        this.ipProdCod = event.detail.value;
    }
    handleIpSerNumChange(event) {
        this.ipSerNumber = event.detail.value;
    }
    handleIPFunLocChange(event) {
        this.ipFunLocation = event.detail.value;
    }
    handleIpLocChange(event) {
        this.ipLocation = event.detail.value;
    }

    @api ipData = [];
    @track caselinepaginate = [];

    @api selectedIpRecords = [];
    @api newarray = [];
    @api cachearray = [];
    @api displaySelectedIpRecords = [];
    @api error;
    @api ipcolumns = ipcolumns;
    @api caselinecolumns = caselinecolumns;
    @api urlid;
    @api locid;

    @track modalContainer;
    @api ipdatalst = [];
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;
    @api displayTotalLengh;
    @api displayTotalSelectLength = 0;

    @track draftValues = [];
    linestatus = [];
    initialRecords;


    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CaseLine_OBJECT })
    caseLineMetadata;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$caseLineMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: LINESTATUS_FIELD
    })

  

getting the below error
edit_ip_tnm.js-meta.xml : Save Failed. Error Invalid reference SVMXC__Case_Line__c.SVMXC__Line_Status__c of type sobjectField in file edit_ip_tnm.js: Source


Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_versioning.htm&release=248&type=5

This problem has nothing to do with changing the LWC component version. The error indicates that a field does not exist.

@sander I tried saving with Lightning Studio basically with a different editor I was able to save with the updated API version

i tried saving with lightning studio i were able to save with updated API version
